# Greenplum ERROR: Canceling query because of high VMEM usage

Tags: memory, errors, greenplum

We have a GreenPlum Cluster which we have set up recently and getting this error on a single query run:

current group id is 140611, group memory usage 40720 MB, group shared memory quota is 31320 MB, slot memory quota is 0 MB, global freechunks memory is 1044 MB, global safe memory threshold is 1048 MB (runaway_cleaner.c:197) SQL state: XX0

I'll be happy to post the settings we currently have in place that may help able to troubleshoot further.

Here are some basic ones I can share:

Cluster has got 128GB RAM on each node host
SWAP on each Node is 32GB

```
 groupid  |   groupname   | concurrency | cpu_rate_limit | memory_limit | memory_shared_quota | memory_spill_ratio | memory_auditor | cpuset
 24964400 | my_user_group    | 10          | 60             | 60           | 80                  | 0                  | vmtracker      | -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ERROR: Canceling query because of high VMEM usage](https://community.pivotal.io/s/question/0D50e0000586mDdCAI/error-canceling-query-because-of-high-vmem-usage?language=en_US) on the vmware Tanzu Community by [Faisal Ali](https://community.pivotal.io/s/profile/0050P000007YjItQAK):

> "Canceling query because of high VMEM usage" is when the segments uses 90% ( default ) of the gp_vmem_protect_limit. If it's the same query with the same error all the time, it would be better to check how much memory is the query using and take a explain plan to understand the query execution path and fine tune the query.